# QTextTable QTextCursor current row?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a `QTextTable` and I want to insert a row in my current position.

How can I know in which row is the `QTextCursor`?

Comment: Can't you use [`cellAt(QTextCursor)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexttable.html#cellAt-2)?

Comment: Yes!!! My solution is `cursor.currentTable().insertRows(cursor.currentTable().cellAt(cursor).row()+1,1)`. Can you write like an answer to mark like solution?

Comment: I believe you could write it as your own answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help @musicamente
the solution for insert a row in a QTextTable in current position is:

`cursor.currentTable().insertRows(cursor.currentTable().cellAt(cursor).row()+1,1)`